# Mirth: Send file like PDF, zip or Transfer pdf files using mirth

Tags: mirth

I want to transfer pdf/zip file through mirh.

I am using file reader connector as source and file writer as destination connector.

can any one help me how to send/transfer pdf/zip file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Set Incoming data: Delimited text
- File type: Binary
- Outgoing filetype also has to be Binary, otherwise the data are corrupted.
- Outgoing template has to be ${message.rawData}

see screen shot for more info.

Channel settings [summary]

[image]

Channel settings [Source]

[image]

Channel settings [Destination]

[image]

Comment: Does this work for .zip files. I have similar requirement.

Comment: It is not working for ZIP files. A zip file is generating without any files in it. If you guys find a solution for it pls let me know. I do have a similar requirement

Comment: @Sid Just passed through this post once again. I achieved zip files by writing the JAVA code. https://hl7engine.wordpress.com/2017/11/27/how-to-create-zip-file-with-multiple-files-in-mirth/

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = "D:/ftproot/PDF/Source";
var fileName = $('fieldId')+".pdf";
var srcpath=source +"\\"+ fileName
var directory = "D:/ftproot/PDF/Target" 
var outFileName = $('fieldId')+".pdf";
var destination = directory +"/" + outFileName

importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(org.apache.commons.io);
//var file = new java.io.File(directory);
var inputFile = new File(srcpath);
var outputFile = new File(destination);
FileUtils.copyFile(inputFile,outputFile);
```

For Transfer your PDF file from one location to another location .You don't need to bother about that.

Place the above code in your Destination trasfarmer .

The above code will pic the PDF file **D:/ftproot/PDF/Source** from this path and copied the PDF file in to the another mentioned location i.e **D:/ftproot/PDF/Target**
.You can directly read the file in Mirth using

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(org.apache.commons.io);
```

Copy the PDF file using

```
FileUtils.copyFile(inputFile,outputFile);
```