# Mirth Connect to send file to a port number

Tags: port, hl7, mirth-connect

Can we use Mirth Connect to send a text file to a particular port?

Thanks,
Ko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; file transfer can be achieved with Mirth Connect.

Create a channel with Source Connector Type = File Reader. Set the source folder path and pooling frequency. Set the other parameters as per your need.

Then setup Destination with File Writer and other parameters as per your need.

Refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945965/5779732

http://wiki.patesco.ca/doku.php?id=hl7:mirth:tutorial

https://amarnathks.wordpress.com/tag/mirth-beginner-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are multiple ways to accomplish this. Files can be transmitted and written over tcp, http, ftp. With the embedded rhino engine, you could also build your own custom implementation should you need to.

Mirth user guide is a very good resource, I suggest reading it in full: https://bridge.nextgen.com/media/3244/mirth-data-sheet-mirth-connect-3-5-user-guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, file transfer can be achieved with Mirth Connect:

Create a channel with Source Connector Type = Java Script Reader, File Reader, or as per your requirement. Set the source folder path and pooling frequency.
Now set the Destination connector type = SMTP Sender or others.

e.g.: SMTP Sender: here you can configure your SMTP details like port number, sender, to mailId, Body, etc

[image: kindly take a look in this image, this will give more idea]